# Moving std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator

Trying the make simple piece of code work:

```
std::thread threadFoo;

std::thread&& threadBar = std::thread(threadFunction);

threadFoo = threadBar; // thread& operator=( thread&& other ); expected to be called
```

Getting an error:

> use of deleted function 'std::thread& std::thread::operator=(const
>   std::thread&)'

I explicitly define `threadBar` as an rvalue reference, not a ordinary one. Why is not expected operator being called? How do I move one thread to another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Named** references are lvalues. Lvalues don't bind to rvalue references. You need to use `std::move`.

```
threadFoo = std::move(threadBar);
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Do I get it right that the one (and the only?) way the expected operator could be used is with a temporary thread object like `threadFoo = std::thread(threadFunction);`?

Comment: Either a temporary or an unnamed reference as you get from `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

See also [`std::thread::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/swap/). This could be implemented as

```
std::thread threadFoo;
std::thread threadBar = std::thread(threadFunction);
threadBar.swap(threadFoo);
```